# Merge all changes from one branch by one user to another branch.

Tags: svn

I have two branches that are similar. One has many changes by a specific user. How do I merge all his changes to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify the user, but you can specify the *revisions* that the user committed, and only merge those changes over to the other branch. Let's say the user made revisions 1001, 1005, and 1008 on `branch1` and you want to merge them to `branch2`:

```
$ export REPO="http://svn.vegicorp.com/svn"
$ svn co $REPO/branches/branch2
$ cd branch2
$ svn merge -c1001 -c1005 -c1008 $REPO/branches/branch1
$ svn commit
```

I checked out `branch2` because that's the branch I want to modify.

Comment: Wrong format (and option) for merge, **must** be (for cherry-pick merge) `svn merge -c 1001 -c 1005 -c 1008 ...`